# Problem at sending email with SwiftMailer library in Laravel 5.5.44

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I have this problem in Laravel 5.5.44 with Swift Mailer package trying to sending emails. This is the mail that the Swift Mailer package send to the server responsible for sending e-mails to the users:

```
This is the mail system at host user-ws.localdomain.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<cxxx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.26] said:
    550-5.7.1 [41.X.X.X] The IP address sending this message does not have a
    PTR 550-5.7.1 record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages
    from IPs 550-5.7.1 with missing PTR records. Please visit 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.1 information. p10-v6si4248809wrw.296 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
    command)
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message that you received from googlemail is quite clear:

> As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from IPs 550-5.7.1 with
>   missing PTR records.

This means that the domain that you use in the `FROM:` header of your mail must have a DNS A-record pointed to the IP address of the host from which the email was sent.

To clarify:

- your domain: example.com
- your FROM adress: whitejson@example.com
- your IP: 1.2.3.4
  A-Record of domain example.com must map to IP 1.2.3.4 in your DNS server.

If the server is only in your local network it will be impossible to send a mail to googlemail that does not comply with this rule.

If you want to earn +2 reputation then mark this answer as accepted.